# Assigning pointers to pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, radix

I have pointer to pointers to char set as:

```
    char **A;
    char **B;
```

I am making string sorting using Radix-Sort, and i have to sort it a few times, but if I sort it, it's just sorting array `A` and saves the result in array `B`. What I want to do, is to assign `A` to be `B`, which is already almost-sorted `A`, but when I do:

```
    A = B;
```

I just set the pointers, right? Which means `A` points now at `B`. And, when I later reassign values I have multiple results of same string. For example:

```
    A = {"aa", "ba", "bc", "bd"};
```

After sorting and using `A = B`, the output looks like:

```
    B = {"aa", "aa", "bc", "bd"};
```

I also tried using `memcpy()` - which should copy what `B` points at to place that is pointed by `A`, correct? But result is the same. No idea how to get this to work. Wasn't sure whether to post here full code, so I uploaded it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BahAMZ1f).

Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit2: With a bit help, changed it and it works fine with `memcpy()`, but it still doesn't 'stable' sorts, and instead of `B = {"bb", "bc"}` I have the opposite: `B = {"bc", "bb"}`. I'm still fighting it, but with no results... yet.

```
void CSort(int p){

int k = 123;
int C[k];
int i;

for(i = 0; i <= k; i++){
    C[i] = 0;
}

for(i = 0; i < ILE; i++){
    C[(int)As[i][p]]++;
}

for(i = 1; i <= k; i++){
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];
}

for(i = 0; i < ILE; i++){     // ile means how many words there are
    Bs[C[(int)As[i][p]] - 1] = As[i];
    printf("As[%i][%i] == %c ", i, p, As[i][p]);
    printf("C[%i] == %i ", (int)As[i][p], C[(int)As[i][p]]-1);
    printf("  Bs[%i]  == %s \n", C[(int)As[i][p]] - 1, Bs[C[(int)As[i][p]] - 1]);

    //(As[i], Bs[C[(int)As[i][p]]], sizeof(As[i]));
    C[(int)As[i][p]]--;
}


}
```

This is my Counting Sort, and here comes my radix:

```
void RSort(int d){
    int i;
    for(i = d; i >= 0; i--){
        CSort(i);
        memcpy(As, Bs, sizeof(*As) * ILE);
    }
}
```

I haven't even got idea - why - because on paper, it works just fine!

To fix my problem, all i had to do, was to change order in last loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < ILE; i++)
```

change to

```
for(i = ILE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

And everything works just fine!

Comment: The problem is in your code. Try to strip it down and copy the stripped version here.

Comment: your poiters to pointers are uninitialized half the time, and the code you posted here assigns addresses of _constants_ to pointers, they are read-only, and can't be messed with. Besisdes: `sizeof(ptr_var)` is probably 4 (or 8, if 64bit)

Comment: `A = {"aa", "ba", "bc", "bd"};` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign

```
 A = B;
```

you assign `A` to point to the same memory `B` points at, not `A` to point at `B`.

In order to copy the array you would need to allocate memory to hold it and memcpy all contents from `B` to `A`

```
char ** A = malloc(sizeof(*A) * numitems);
memcpy(A, B, sizeof(*A) * numitems);
```

Then if you sort `A` or `B` it will not affect the other because you have copies.